# Is it wrong to refer to myself as a god?(Not to be worshipped or anything like that)

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy

So let me say this right of the bat, I by no means am referring to myself as an equivalent to Allah I never have and never will. I view Allah as an omnipotent being one who can do anything he wills with no correlation to what is logically possible and what is not. I use the term God differently. For me it means someone who can do anything they want, someone who believes in their own confidence, and one who is independent and able to manifest their goals with work. I use it to refer to myself to motivate myself. I by no means am asking for others to call me a god, infact I do not want them to, I use this to inspire myself and motivate me. Because I dissociate my definition of God from Allah would this be permissible.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't call anyone and above all not yourself a god. Although it is English, this word is reserved to Whom it belongs.

You can call anyone or yourself a king (unless you are living in a kingdom that forbids this by stately law). That should be enough.

Answer (score -3):

The semantics is very important. There is no wrong in using the word "god" for someone other than Allah if by that word "god", you actually mean something that does not make an equal to Allah.

There is a better example. You can even use the word "rabb" to mean "master" and that won't mean associating partners with Allah. See this.

يَـٰصَـٰحِبَىِ ٱلسِّجْنِ أَمَّآ أَحَدُكُمَا فَيَسْقِى رَبَّهُۥ خَمْرًا ۖ وَأَمَّا ٱلْـَٔاخَرُ فَيُصْلَبُ فَتَأْكُلُ ٱلطَّيْرُ مِن رَّأْسِهِۦ ۚ قُضِىَ ٱلْأَمْرُ ٱلَّذِى فِيهِ تَسْتَفْتِيَانِ

[12/41](https://quran.com/12/41)